# laravel aws serverless after login expired 419

Tags: laravel-7, aws-serverless, bref

I have Laravel 7 bref deploy to aws serverless.

after login, laravel create 3 session to database session but the result show

```
419 page expired (SESSION_DRIVER=database).
```

tried using the `SESSION_DRIVER=cookie`, but the result is still the same `419 page expired`.

What mistake am i doing?

Comment: after change the config ckear the config and cache, then try again `php artisan cache:clear`  `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I have done this every time I have deployed, php artisan config:clear, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan view:clear. I think there are settings on the server that are not correct

Comment: does `SESSION_DRIVER=file` works?

Comment: tried all SESSION_DRIVER : file / database / cookie. the result is 419 page expired

Comment: @sta how to enable lambda session, csrf token, and jwt?

Comment: hello is this problem solved?